# How to kill a MATLAB Batch Process ran by Qt QProcess?

Tags: python, matlab, qt, pyqt, qprocess

I currently have a Python program that calls a MATLAB script as batch like so:

```
matlab = QProcess()
matlab.start('matlab -noFigureWindows -batch "cd(users/script_directory/); MyScript.m;"')
#^ command to start MATLAB batch process in CMD
```

The issue I'm running into is that once this batch process starts, there's no way to kill it. So if my Python app gets force-closed, the MATLAB script keeps running and causes all sorts of issues, meaning I need to kill the process on app close.

I'm calling the MATLAB script as a QProcess and get the following message when I force-close the Python app before the MATLAB script finishes executing:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("matlab") is still running.
```

With this, how do I stop the batch MATLAB process? Using 'ctrl-c' in CMD works for me sometimes to kill the process but I need it to be consistent to make the Python work right.

Similarly, can I just have it 'force quit' or 'restart' batch MATLAB or anything along those lines to clear all running processes?

Comment: How would you normally terminate the shown matlab batch command if started at the command line?

Answer (score 0):

A brute force way to kill it would be to just kill any matlab process via the [process and system utilities library](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) at the start of your application:

```
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name().lower() == 'matlab.exe':
        process.terminate()
```